# Lithium-ion battery charger circuit design

Tags: design, solar-cell, lithium-ion, charger, solar-energy

For my project I need to charge a 2s, 7.4V LiPo battery pack from an 18V 10W solar panel. This would not be an issue if I was able to use ICs such as the BQ2057WTS, but I am required to do design a circuit in place of the IC using parts lying around lab (Transistors, voltage regulators, op-amps etc.).

LiPo batteries require careful charging using a method called CC/CV (Constant current/ Constant voltage) where the battery first charges with a constant current and rising voltage to a specific point and then undergoes constant voltage charging where the voltage is kept constant and the current is changing until the battery is fully charged.

I am currently struggling with the design of this specific circuit in place of the IC to ensure the battery is not damaged, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Update: My supervisor finally agreed to let me use the arduino ATMEGA328P microcontroller to aid with the design. Therefore, am I correct in saying that I can make use of the ADC channels to measure the voltage of the battery and control the separate CC/CV accordingly?

**____________________________________**

Battery - Ansmann 7.4V, 2600 mAh.    [**Datasheet here**](https://budgetbatteries.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/LI-ION2S1P.pdf)
Nominal charge 0.5C, max charge 1C, endpoint charge 0.01C.
Vmax 8.4V +/- 1%
Temperature: Charge 0 - +45C, Discharge -20 - +60C, Storage -20 - +40C

Comment: Could you please share what design you have so far? Then there is something more specific to discuss..

Comment: Doing this with pure analog electronics sounds like madness to me. Kind of like replacing a MCU with discreet logic circuits. What's the reason you can't use an IC?

Comment: Li+ charge controllers must observe the ambient temperature as charging should only begin with an ambient temperature between 0C and 40C. 45C is permissible (for a number of batteries - check the datasheet) for charging to continue. You will also need to design a cell balancing circuit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LI Ion battery charger?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20ion%20battery%20charger)

Comment: At a very minimum you must define climatic range, battery chemistry, C range and desired C rates  CC= C rate TBD, CV = 4.0 to 4.2 ( TBD depends on life cycle spec vs capacity),  Cutoff = 10% of CC during CV.  There are almost infinite solutions and failure without specs

Comment: This sounds like an unwise assignment.  If the restrictions are on projects in general, and it was *your decision* to make a battery charger, you should change to a safer project or at least a different battery type.  If the restrictions were imposed *by someone knowing* you are making a lithium battery balance charger, your instructor is being irresponsible - especially if they leave you turning to the Internet for advice.

Comment: Assuming that it is a good idea to do this in discrete circuitry (doubtful at best), do you have a conceptual diagram (at least) of what the architecture of such a charger would look like?

Comment: How can you be stuck on the project when you have the  BQ2057WTS block diagram and logic available to you. From this information you can derive a specification for your analog charger; since you already know you want to use a CC/CV charge curve this should be easy.

Comment: @JackCreasey great suggestion but for this simple requirement. He only needs half of the functionality : Vbat detection, current sensing , Current switch, Cutoff logic and indictator

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Obviously ….and he can derive how much of the capability needed to provide a solution. Having a datasheet is still a huge lift ...and makes the task much easier.

Comment: Why is it that no one sees the **obvious mismatch** in PV voltage and battery voltage effects on a PV power conversion?

Comment: Protection often includes OVP, OCP, OTP and in/out reverse [protection] but with only 18 V and a 2S battery pack capable of storing 20Wh you need to consider switched voltage conversion with inductive energy storage and OCP is not going to be an issue here. Is this too advanced?

Comment: Despite the "cries of alarm" this is a not too hard a task. Two important aspects are 1. When is this required to be finished by? & 2. What is the fullest possible specification of what is required? What is:  Battery brand and model if known, datasheet link if known? Battery Wh / Ah / Ichg_max,  Do you need/want to charge battery to nearly full capacity or would ~= 80% capacity with much longer cycle life be OK? (ie if you stop at end of CC then CV not needed and you get less capacity but better lifetime), ...

Comment: Do you need/want to implement protection features such as tickle-up charge under 2.5V (or wherever), full lock out under say 2V (I recently almost had a house fire because a charger did NOT do this :-) :-( !), cell temperature monitoring, environment temperature monitoring. || An Arduino will allow a charger with all bells and whistles, if desired. | Do you want to make full use of 18V panel energy? - as Sunnyskyguy notes - if you do then a buck converter/downconverter is needed - need not necessarily be MPPT . If a converter is used, do you have to design and build  that too? | PV panel spec?

Comment: I do indeed have to design and build that to, its basically a blind sun tracker for on top of a small RC car to lengthen the battery life. The solar panel has to charge the battery pack ( Ansmann 7.4V, 2600mAh (RS components is down this weekend for maintenance so unfortunately I cannot get the datasheet)). I am not required to implement "bells and whistles", I basically just need a charger that will lengthen the battery life the RC car

Comment: @Zee96 WHEN IS THIS DUE BY? || Why an 18V panel? Why 10 W - Is that mandatory. | Please put ALL AVAILABLE information into your question so easily seen and not lost. | A 2.6 Ah battery will usually charge at 2.6A max. Pmaxchg ~~= 2.6 x 7.4 ~= 19W  SO battery can absorb all available energy. So the "real" main task is an MPPT charger or at leaat a step down converter. | an eg BQ2057WTS, will **NOT** meet your spec as it is NOT an energy converting converter [Datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2057c.pdf) - see fig 1 for basic cct. You need to be fully clear on what the aim is ...

Comment: If the aim is MAX USE OF AVAILABLE ENERGY then you MUST have an energyconverter (Vpanel <> Vcell) and ideally MPPT. Is this REALLY what is being asked for ? Really? Really. Max voltage NEEDED is about 8.4V - say 9V. A 9V panel would be a MUCH better fit. 10V or ... . Is 18C Vmp panel necessary?

Comment: Zee you really need to answer the questions. Also considering the size of the panel next to (not)my motorcycle, you can't do solar tracking and operate the vehicle at the same time. and it would make a heavy spoiler !  i.e. not practical weight for extending battery life while operating. due to energy lost moving this weight

Comment: Zee also write down all the details Russ is telling you. It matters. Battery University site also , is a must read. But sounds like as your first a 5 month project rather than a week with experience. Specs first , design second..

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Comment only: An 18% efficient panel needs 0.1 m^2. Achievable with std cells. Not tiny. You can get over 20% cells at higher cost. That's say 316mm x 316mm or 400mm x 250mm or ... .  On a vehicle you can use a PCB backed panel rather than the more solid unit in your photo. Still not a trivial item.

Comment: I was referring to linear charger  efficiency  not the PV  (LDO 18V in 8.2V * 450mA but its closer to 40%~50% best case  but I take your point for a thin panel, but I thought I read steerable tracking

Comment: @Zee96 I added battery datasheet link and charging data to your question. Please add whatever else you have - especially panel data. Do you REALLY want to steer a panel on a moving car ? 2 axis rocking would work. Windage an issue. Drag = 600 x A x (V/10)^2 Newton. A = areal projection of panel area to windflow - meter^2.

Comment: Microcontroller: Could control buck converted by a few transistor or opamp converter would do OK. Measure Vpanel, Vbat - control converter to optimise panel at Vmp (pseudo MPPT), ensure Ichg < I max. Vbat <= Vmax. ... Easiest sun optimisation is probably a GPS with car 'compass' angle and almanac giving sun position and angle. Tilt panel X and Y rock motors to point panel normal to sun.  Sensors: Vp, Vbat, Ip, Ibat. ...

Comment: @JackCreasey re "how can you be stuck" -> Alas, the BQ2057WTS is not a good match to the task as described. As SunnySkyGuy... notes, an 18Vmp panel charging a 8V4 max battery (and 6V min) with a linear regulator will have an efficincy between 6/16 = 33% and 8.4/18 =~ 47%. The rest is necessarily lost as heat. (Actually, direct connection increases Ichg to about Isc which is SLIGHTLY higher than Imp. A buck converter or equivalent is essential.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I suggested a buck convertor but that does NOT imply an MPPT design. This was clearly a scholastic project which has changed in a major fashion now that an MCU is allowed. In fact it's almost a different question with the MCU allowed. As to how the OP can be 'stuck' when there is rich data available astounds me. For reference a true MPPT solution would work whether the PV panel voltage was below or above the battery voltage as it's tracking the best power point so would require Buck/Boost DC-DC convertor.

Comment: @JackCreasey I agree with a downconverter doesn't have to be an MPPT converter - but once you have the buck then at least psuedo MPPT is easy - ie as Linear Tech and others do - you load the panel until it is at Vmp with an allowance (rising V) with rising current. This doesn't work as well for very low light (as Vmppt_low light  < Vmp_high light but is otherwise not too bad. | FWIW note that I said: "...So the "real" main task is an MPPT charger or at least a step down converter..." &

Comment: ... & " ... If the aim is MAX USE OF AVAILABLE ENERGY then you MUST have an energyconverter (Vpanel <> Vcell) and ideally MPPT. ..." & " ... Could control buck converted by a few transistor or opamp converter would do OK. Measure Vpanel, Vbat - control converter to optimise panel at Vmp (pseudo MPPT) ..." -> ie we are in goodish agreement over converter etc.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon BUT, the question was originally using analog components around the Lab …..not a fully fledged design by any means. I still suggest that MPPT was going too far. Simplicity and understanding of the problem stace was the objective of the school exercise.

Comment: Now that an Arduino is in the project scope, it appears bigger exercise. A simple buck regulator won't work as the input impedance shunts the PV source impedance being ~18V/0.45A= 40 Ohms minimum thus reducing available power @ 18V so a PMT buck regulates the input impedance to match. I say it's a conjugate match to PV Cout + ESR + Cin added. to Zin of switched inductor.+ RdsOn. So it is a analog problem not solved by an Arduino.

Comment: ASK your prof about Conjugate Impedance Matching this PV current source and why/how a Max Power Tracking SMPS does this here. They ought to understand Zequiv.  of the PV is >= 40 Ohms. and rises to high Z at low Solar input from VI curve and load line. 2S Battery can be modelled at 10% Soc as 6V + ESR + 10kFarads.  from V/Ah * k.

Comment: @Zee96 The critical question to answer: **WHEN - IS - THIS - DUE  BY - ?**

Comment: @Zee96 Fullish charger spec added.

Answer (score 3):

Like most problems, you should start this one by breaking it down into simpler problems. A practical design would almost certainly use a microcontroller or an IC to do this, but there's no reason you couldn't build something out of more discrete ICs. Doing so could be instructive.

- Do you need and how would you make a circuit that measures temperature to ensure it's appropriate to charge the batteries?
- Do you need and how would you make a circuit that detects when it's time to stop charging and turns everything off until it's time to charge again?
- How do you want to switch the current? Will your switching be linear or will you use an inductor to step down the voltage making a more complicated but more efficient design that scales better?
- How would you make a circuit that detects and limits current during CC charging?
- How would you make a circuit that detects and limits voltage during CV charging?
- Do you need and how would you make a circuit that limits current to a lower level if the voltage is below a certian limit.
- Can you combine the above parts by sharing elements like the switching elements so you only have one high current/high power transistor?
- How do you make the device safe? What could fail and how could it fail and how do you protect users and valuable parts of your circuit if they do? (MOSFETS tend to fail closed so it's a challenge to break a circuit when they start to fail if you don't have some sort of fuse)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Ill try answer as best as I possibly as even I am slightly unsure of what my supervisor wants!

1) In the edit, I have added that I am able to use a ATMEGA328P Micro controller, so to measure temperature i was going to use an ADC pin with a thermistor.

2) Hopefully using the functionality of the ATMEGA328p i can measure the voltage in the battery and get the circuit to react accordingly.

Comment: For the rest of the questions, I am yet to figure out as I have just been told that I can use the ATMEGA328p, I am really hoping this will aid in acting as the "brain" of my charger.

Comment: If you have trouble with an external temperature sensor, it looks like there's one on the ATMEGA328P.

To measure battery voltage you'll want to divide it with a pair of resistors and compare it with a fixed supply or reference... but you'll also want to limit it and that's still typically done with an analog circuit or dedicated ICs.

Answer (score 0):

## There are two fundamental choices

- trivial  FET switch with 8.2 to 8.4V comparator latch off FET  - 1hr job  power loss > 50%,**why bother**!
- complex MPT Buck regulator with above . Learn many ways how to conjugate match PV current source to a 10 kilofarad load 2S Li-Ion pack from 18 to 8.2V  This is NOT a logic problem. ( Ardiuino) but an RF switched SMPS problem ( if you accept the challenge)
- A simple Buck regulator will never work. It will just drag PV voltage down to 4~6V The impedance here is > 40 Ohms at max PV power and Z rises as solar power reduces. **Don't believe me try out a simple Buck 18 to 8V regulator and see why this is true.**  due to lack of load regulation from Zin mismatch.

## N.B.

The biggest design challenge is how to get 18V, 10W from a mismatched V/I capacitive load and V/I current source. If you put 18V 450mA source into a 7.4 to 8.4 2S Li-Ion battery being charged < 1/2 power conversion efficiency.

e.g.  Power Efficiency  = 21% = (8.4V*0.45A)/18W out of the 18V PV panel to charge  the battery.  Thus a PMT PV controller is needed more than a simple Vbat cutoff regulator which is trivial.

## Panel Assumptions

- Pmax =18W **Solar Panel**: Monocrystalline silicon 18V 10W @ 0.55A
- Voc= No-load voltage: 18-23VDC  (depending on solar power)
- Load voltage: 12V  (<6W)
- Output current: 400~450mA  Isc = 550mA (Max.)

[image]

[image]

## Considerations

- 4.2 * 8.4V charge voltage is mismatched with 18V photovoltaic (PV) panel,
  which is a solar-powered current-source ( thus MPT buck pre-regulator  needed)

  - Since 450mA charge current is much less than Li Ion typ. charge currents, CC is not needed
  - Assuming std Li-Ion cells 4.2V CV and 1A rates with 10% cuttoff or 100mA for CCV cutoff = 100% SoC,
  - Current sense with 100mV drop at 0.5A = 50mW requires 0.1V/0.5A= 200 mΩ current shunt on low side for ease of comparing to 0.1V Vref (stable)

## - Design requirements :

- Test criteria = Design Specs
- Buck converter for MPT on PV  18V to 8.4v
- Vmax detection and I cutoff sense 8.2~8.4V  50~100mA cutoff
- over voltage protection 8.42V and I cutoff "logic" for shut off
- Power-on or periodic reset
- LED bar indicator options,  Off/On charge state,  State of Charge indicator 6.6V to 7.4 Green  7.4V  to  8.4V RED during charge .

[image]

**my conceptual idea in simulator**

Analog optimization of PV current source and Capacitance using quasi-resonant **Conjugate matched Buck impedance** step-down converter with automated Hysteresis cut-off and startup.  ( Ask your prof about this)  An Arduino won't help there. All I used was a comparator with setpoint for cutoff with LED indicator for Charging with a critical setting of hysteresis thresholds using 5.0V = Vref not shown.

Cin provides the boost ripple current to 10uH @ 75kHZ switched at 50% duty cycle must be Film Cap for high ripple current.

[image]

Comment: I wonder who does not understand this design issue ? -1 and is afraid to comment

Comment: Professional Engineers learn to ask questions and not be too quick to judge (-1)

Comment: Who on earth would advocate an MPPT design for a simple battery charger based on available analog devices?  I'd imagine the OP is expected to show some diligence in dealing with the difference in solar panel output voltage and provide a CC/CV profile for the batteries. The OP might also be expected to show the weaknesses in the design, such as lower efficiency. The suggestions here are simply over the top. I added a -1.

Comment: This shows your lack of understanding.  When a 10W charger at 18V drives a battery at 8.2V battery the series power loss is 50% thus the OP then faces a heatsink issue because someone overlooked the details. This is not the situation for an LDO with disable switch and who needs CC regulation if 10W is only 450mA into a 20Wh battery back capable of 10A, besides he'll never see 10W charge power and then wonder why....

Comment: A simple DC-DC buck convertor (within the potential of available analog components)  solves the problem. Change the 18V to say 12V and you reduce losses without the complexity. Any given battery has charge current limits, both CC and for CV trickle so you DO have to be aware of and control the current.

Comment: that's MUCH  better  now make small changes to regulate at 8.4 then cutoff after 1 minute or when Ic drops to 10% or 50mA. The IC you referred to has OR logic using 2 inputs to driver

Comment: I like this idea, and I looked into a buck converter to step down the voltage and increase current for a faster charge, however, I do not understand why the CC charging part will be unnecessary since the current is low?

Comment: http://sound.whsites.net/articles/lithium-charging.htm

Comment: Have a look at figure 2 on this website and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: you can double the output current when the voltage is divided in half, but the control loop can be unstable as the buck step-down regulator has a variable load impedance on a current source, so an MPT regulator has special compensation for this.  If V=LdI/dt  the effective ESR or  ΔV/ ΔI of the buck regulator must match the PV panel for MPT operating point.

Comment: For the scope of the project the solar panel will be following the sun as to ensure the panel is continually delivering max power.

Comment: figure 2 is almost correct for a 2.5A charger but the PV can only deliver 10W or 450mA @ 18V and Battery University proves that the time you spend above 4V degrades battery life causing reduced total life cycles. so cutoff should have occurred at 10% CC or .25A, just before 2hours.

Comment: The secret for MPT regulator is for the buck to match the impedance of the PV at max power, just as I showed in my chart.  so Vmp/Imp ~ 40 Ohms  (=18V/0.45A) also ΔV/ ΔI = 40 ohms which is what the Buck regulator Zin avg needs to be.  More complex yet 2x the output current.

Comment: @F.Ahmed  Sure a linear regulator does the job but dissipating half the solar power in the regulator best case, but I see you are a beginner.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I mentioned "pseudo MPPT" such as is implemented by LT and others in PV energy harvesting ICs. They claim the result to be within a % or few of true MPPT. You alter the load on the panel to hold panel voltage at Vmp and deliver the resultant energy to the battery at whatever voltage it is at at present if in CC stage and Ichg < Ichgmax. They do not do it BUT adding a small rise in panel V above Vmp as I load rises tracks closer to tru7e MPPT and (impprtantly) compensation for panel temperature increases power usefully. As I'm sure you appreciate, none of this is overly hard..

Comment: ... Stability is not liable to be overly hard to maintain. Panel voltage slew rate can be limited by choice of a smoothing cap. This system "needs work" at very low insolation levels (not usually of major concern energy contribution wise). At low insolation Vmp falls below the relatively fixed value across most of the range. Allowing the panel to rise to typical Vmp decreases panel input wrt optimum. Odd are the very low available energy at typical Vmp will be enough of a clue to lower target Vmp in these conditions. Some 'playing' would probably suggest what empirical trimming is in order.

Comment: @Zee96 As requested by you - comment on fig 2 . CCT is OK if efficiency not required. LM317 in Vreg mode drops 1.25V for internal supply powering and an additional 1 - 1.5V due to pass transistor depending on current. As a current source it drops 1.25V. So for that cct you lose 1.25 + (1 to 1.5+) + 1.25 = 3.5 to 4V for in your case 6 to 8.4V output. So best efficiency you can get is 8.4/(8.4 + 3.5) =~ 70%. ie youthrow 30% of your energy away by using LM317s. D1 is designed to add inefficincy. **IF** you care about panel to battery efficiency you need a totally different approach. Spec needed.

Answer (score 0):

Tentative charger specification:

The following outlines the required functionality to implement an efficient energy converting pseudo MPPT charger. It implements CCCV charging, low voltage trickle up, very low battery voltage charging disable, maximum current charge limiting, pseudo MPPT with insolation compensation, PV panel temperature compensation, and battery over and under temperature lockout.

Availability of a  microcontroller with analogue digital Converters and PWM digital output is assumed.

- Provide a buck converter controlled by the microcontroller.  this could be implemented almost completely in software with a transistor switch controlled by the microcontroller,  or if desired, a reference voltage could be  provided by the microcontroller to a discrete buck converter.
- Provide small current sense resistors in the PV panel ground lead and battery ground lead.
  and use simple op-amp amplifiers to increase the voltage from the sense resistors to a sensible level for the microcontroller ADCs.
- Use voltage dividers to allow measurement of the PV panel voltage and battery voltage by the motor controller.
- Use a thermistor or  or RTD to measure PV panel temperature
- Use a thermistor or RTD to measure battery temperature.
- Charge the battery from the PV panel using the buck converter.
- Monitor PV panel voltage and change the loading from the buck converter so that the panel tracks a desired MPPT curve - ie  V_ panel =  Vmp modified  by PV panel current,  battery temperature etc.   ie The desired panel voltage will rise slightly with increasing PV current and will fall steeply at the very low current and to compensate for very low insolation conditions  and will compensate for panel temperature.
- If battery voltage is below the battery maximum of about 8.4 volts charge at maximum available energy as long as I charge is below I charge Max of 1C.
- If battery voltage = battery voltage maximum of about 8.4 volts operate in constant voltage mode and monitor battery current until  end point current is reached
- If battery voltage is less than 2.5 volts per cell limit charging to say 0.1 C or some other designed limit.
- If battery voltage is less than 2 volts per cell prevent charging
- If battery  temperature exceeds 40° C prevent charging
- If battery temperature is below 0 degrees C prevent charging

**___________________________________**

Answers from Andrew and Sunnyskyguy provide good material for developing you question.   You need a full spec on what is required of you and a full spec of all equipment involved. Once you have those it will be "not too hard" to arrive at a good solution. Please consider this a starting point, with input to follow as more information is provided.

Very importantly - when is this required to be finished by?

Full spec of equipment:

PV panel spec: Vmp, Imp, Wmp, Isc, Voc, ....
Brand , model, Datasheet link?

Battery:  Chemistry (LiPo but ...?) Wh, Vnom, Ah, Imax_chg, Vmax_chg, Tempmaxchg,
Brand, model, datasheet link.

Charging spec:

Do you need/want to charge battery to nearly full capacity or would ~= 80% capacity with much longer cycle life be OK? (ie if you stop at end of CC then CV not needed and you get less capacity but better lifetime), ...

Do you need/want to implement protection features such as
low rate trickle-up charge under 2.5V (or wherever),
full lock out under say 2V (I recently almost had a house fire because a charger did NOT do this
cell temperature monitoring,
environment temperature monitoring.

An Arduino will allow a charger with all bells and whistles, if desired.
Whistling Dixie optional.